# Make "login page" to be a homepage | Don't allow customers to view the website without being logged in

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, login

How can I make the login page my homepage? With no header/footer or any exit links.

So customer has to login or register if he wants to access my website.

If customer is not logged in, the website will be inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this extension](https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login) - you should be able to configure it to block **all** pages

Comment: I have seen this before, but was hoping for a simpler solution :D I'll wait and maybe someone else will have some other ideas :) thank for reaching out!

Comment: Used at the end :)